# Is the _id field in Mondo DB initialized on the client? Or is it initialized in mongo db?

Tags: mongodb, save, document, objectid

I have a question about the _id field in MongoDB.

Application P, currently developed with Spring Boot, will insert documents into Mongo DB while running multiple instances.

But the point at which the document is stored in MongoDB is very important. So, in application P, I'm going to leave the _id field of the document blank and insert it so that an ObjectId is created automatically, and then I'm going to use the ObjectId's timestamp.

I have a question for you here. When saving a document in Mongo DB, if the _id field is empty and the save is attempted, is the _id field initialized in application P or automatically initialized in Mongo DB?

Comment: It depends on the driver. I know the node.js driver creates the _id on the client side. You need to have a careful look at the spring documentation. Why do you think, it makes any difference?

Comment: If I recall correctly, If it presents on the client side, the value is taken from the client, if no, it's added by the server